# How to use Flask to render a VueJS frontend?

Tags: python, vue.js, flask

I know that in a regular Flask project you have to a have a `static`and `templates`folder at the same directory level than `application.py`. In templates you include all your html and in static all your JS.

However, I'm not sure how this should be structured using VueJS.

My application.py file listens to different routes, such as `/ping`and `/books`and based on the JSON object that each route has, different things get rendered by what I run on `localhost:8080`using Vue.

Take into account that this is for deployment, so the WSGI file path is ````application.py```. In other words, I need the Flask routes to render what Vue renders. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you expand on "I need the Flask routes to render what Vue renders"?

Comment: @Chris I basically want to tell Flask return render_template('index.html') which is inside the 'client' folder, not the 'static' folder. Do I need to rename 'client' to 'static' and/or what else should I do?

Comment: Have you reviewed this? It looks like it might be for you: https://github.com/gtalarico/flask-vuejs-template

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

application.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(
     __name__,
     static_folder = 'static',
     template_folder = 'static',
     )
# a simple page that says hello
@app.route('/', defaults = {'path': ''}, methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    return render_template('index.html')
```

static/index.html

```
<html>
     ....
     <script type="text/javascript" src="render.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

render.js is the output of vue-webpack transpilation process that calls other js files within static.